# Fields Not visible in force.com Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I have gone through all the process of creating Force.com Sites and assigned my Visualforce page to site landing page. Am displaying the **Account** fields in VF Page as form input, Problem is

> only picklist fields and Lookup fields of the Account object are displayed in Site URL

In my org VF page, everything is perfect,

> Saw some suggestions on Field-level Security even that seems perfect

Comment: One thing to consider - a force.com site can't update an account, so if you are trying to display inputField for an existing record, I don't think it will let you

Comment: Have you reviewed the FLS in the site’s dedicated profile that you access via the site’s configuration page?

Comment: I would suggest you, use a wrapper for object fields as you will always see FLS issues when it comes to the Force.com sites.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC thanks DC got it, Force.com sites don't allow update operation that caused the issue in my VF page, Glad you helped and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force.com sites don't allow update operation that caused the issue in my VF page, Glad you helped and resolved the issue.